# Python Javascript CryptoJS

Tags: javascript, python, encryption, aes

I am looking for a module that I can use in both python & javascript so that can encrypt something in python then decrypt in javascript if I pass in a key (and vice versa).

So far I've checked out SlowAES and CryptoJS, but cant find any good documentation or examples. Is anyone able to help?

Below is my attempt to get this working:

JS:

```
var encoded_message = 'MTAxMTEyMTMxNDE1MTYxN2asfw3LtCtoL+mvWtJsIVSVCsvZdBIvZWWRuKEI85nd';
var my_iv = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse('1011121314151617');
var my_key = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse('824601be6c2941fabe7fe256d4d5a2b7');

console.log('my iv [' + my_iv + ']');
console.log('my key [' + my_key + ']');
console.log('my enc message [' + encoded_message + ']');

var data = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encoded_message, my_key, { iv: my_iv, mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC });
console.log(data);
var dec = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.stringify(data);
console.log('data [' + dec + ']');


var encoded_message = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse('MTAxMTEyMTMxNDE1MTYxN2asfw3LtCtoL+mvWtJsIVSVCsvZdBIvZWWRuKEI85nd');
console.log('\n\n\n');
console.log('message [' + encoded_message + ']');
```

Python:

```
import os, random, struct
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto import Random
import base64
class AESCipher:
    def __init__(self, key):
        BS = 16
        self.pad = lambda s: s + (BS - len(s) % BS) * chr(BS - len(s) % BS)
        self.unpad = lambda s : s[0:-ord(s[-1])]
        self.key = self.pad(key[0:16])

    def encrypt(self, raw):
        raw = self.pad(raw)
        iv = "1011121314151617"
        cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
        return base64.b64encode(iv + cipher.encrypt(raw))

    def decrypt(self, enc):
        enc = enc.replace(' ', '+')
        enc = base64.b64decode(enc)
        iv = enc[:16]
        cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
        return self.unpad(cipher.decrypt(enc[16:]))


def main():     

    message = 'this is my new message'
    print message[:16]

    cipher = AESCipher('824601be6c2941fabe7fe256d4d5a2b7')
    encrypteddata = cipher.encrypt('work you bloody thing!')
    print encrypteddata         

    decryptdata =cipher.decrypt(encrypteddata)
    print decryptdata 

main()
```

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30990129/encrypt-in-python-decrypt-in-javascript

Comment: Simpler and safer is to just use TLS.

Answer (score 2):

I've recently been using sjcl in Javascript,.. 
http://bitwiseshiftleft.github.io/sjcl/

They also appears to be a python compatible version.
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sjcl

At it's simplest you can just do ->

```
sjcl.encrypt("password", "data")
```

and

```
sjcl.decrypt("password", "encrypted-data")
```

But you still can do low level stuff with it too.

Comment: @LukePark  In what way?

Comment: Well, software recommendations are off-topic, and your answer doesn't solve the problem that the OP is having with their code.

Comment: @LukePark  `I am looking for a module that I can use in both python & javascript so that can encrypt something in python then decrypt in javascript if I pass in a key (and vice versa).`   You see the bit about looking for a module..?

Comment: Yep, sure do.  That is the off-topic part.  I'd assume someone with ~3k rep would know that already.

Comment: @LukePark  It's not of topic, if the topic is asking for a recommendation..  It's not rocket science..

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they..." How long have you been using StackOverflow?

Comment: @LukePark  I never asked the question, keep up.. And `This doesn't solve the OPs problem` its obviously totally incorrect.  Don't try and re-direct your error.

Comment: I feel like this conversation isn't really helping, I feel like you might have misunderstood my point, but no worries.  I'm merely saying that an answer to this question that wouldn't be off-topic would be one that includes reason for **why** the OPs code is not working.  Your answer would be better as a comment.  Didn't mean to personally offend you or anything, have a good day.

Comment: Cheers @keith I encounter this issue when running it in python:
        ``check_mode_ccm()  # check ccm support .   
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sjcl-0.1.7-py2.7.egg/sjcl/sjcl.py", line 69, in check_mode_ccm
    "If you use pycrypto, you need a version >= 2.7a1 (or a special branch)."
Exception: Pycrypto/pycryptodome does not seem to support MODE_CCM. If you use pycrypto, you need a version >= 2.7a1 (or a special branch).``

However the latest branch is pycrypto-2.6.1???

Comment: @darthguinea  I'm not a python user, but they have version  2.7a1  here -> https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/ under experimental..