# unable to decode an encrypted string encrypted from python

Tags: javascript, python, angular, typescript

Here is my code to encrypt and decrypt in python.

```
def encrypt(self, raw, key):
raw = self._pad(raw)
iv = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)
cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
return base64.b64encode(iv + cipher.encrypt(raw))

def decrypt(self, enc, key):
enc = base64.b64decode(enc)
iv = enc[:AES.block_size]
cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
return self._unpad(cipher.decrypt(enc[AES.block_size:])).decode('utf-8')

def _pad(self, s):
return s + (self.bs - len(s) % self.bs) * chr(self.bs - len(s) % self.bs)

@staticmethod
def _unpad(s):
return s[:-ord(s[len(s)-1:])]
```

I want to achieve the same encrypt/decrypt in angular 7 with typescript. I always end up getting an empty string.   Here is my code to encrypt and decrypt in typescript.

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {EncryptionService} from './shared';

import * as CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private encryptionService: EncryptionService) {
  }

  title = 'reactiveForm';

  ngOnInit() {

    const decryptedValue = '8Tp7dEA2MfjL0Q4SF51fLS6oivJtsURyvGQ3q5P9WujZHzfIKZTcRJrfpeQ42T34afV+AkWaTUnmrLxo0jjgHMpS/HVX7KSOUg6G/jNht8Y=';
    const secretKey = 'd8xYs6TtzrkhYcpgvHCNO0DvLu5LFBAA';
    const decrypted = this.decrypt(secretKey, decryptedValue);

    console.log('Decrypted :' + decrypted);
  }

    decrypt(keys, value) {
    const key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(keys);
    const iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(keys);
    const decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(this.decodeBase64(value), key, {
      keySize: 128 / 8,
      iv,
      mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
      padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
    });

    return decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
  };

  encrypt(keys, value) {
    const key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(keys);
    const iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(keys);
    const encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(value.toString()), key,
      {
        keySize: 128 / 8,
        iv,
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
      });

    return encrypted.toString();
  };

  decodeBase64(data) {
    return CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(data);
  }

}
```

I wrote the encryption/decryption in app-component just to test it out it works fine.

Comment: similar question. please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30990129/encrypt-in-python-decrypt-in-javascript

Comment: @jcuypers I tried that out. But still getting an empty string.

Comment: For me you need to check the padding and make sure they are the same.  I've seen a similar problems before. the link was provided  for some troubleshooting ideas.

Comment: @jcuypers Thanks for quick reply. I will check that and will update.

Comment: In all the 'working' examples they state that they changed the python padding to PKCS.7   (as you expect in the angular version)

Comment: As you can see, I am already using the PKCS.7 in my code.

Comment: please check the last post of the link that I have sent.  **explicit PKCS.7 encoding on the python side**